# Word in English to mean "study the convergence / divergence" of a series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Linguistic question. In French we say study the "nature" of the series to mean study if it is convergent or divergent. Is there an equivalent wording in English?

Comment: I usually hear "convergence" used in this way

Comment: "study the nature of the series" is a perfectly valid English sentence, conveying what you explain (though it is not limited just to convergence issues. Just like the French word implies, it can also mean to study if the series is converging fast or slow, if it is positive or alternating, etc.).

Comment: "to study the convergence of something" suffices; for it means "to study whether it converges or not", is not it?

Comment: "Study the series" would be fine too.

Comment: Perhaps better is "investigate the convergence" of a series.

Comment: Thanks guys to help a poor French man who tries to write English.

Comment: "Behaviour" might work too, but it's not used exclusively for speaking of convergence.